# PhP How to send a Session Array to MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am still new to learning how MySQL works and PhP and I have been trying to get my Array values which is part of a session into a MySQL database but I can't figure out how to or what I am doing wrong. I can't get the query to grab certain values out of the array in the function checkouttodatabase().

I've tried following multiple tutorials and posts regarding getting a session array posted into a MySQL database but to no avail. This seems to "function" but doesn't add the item name to the database but instead puts down "Array" and the values "0"

//Adding the item to the array

```
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {

if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
    if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $item_array = array(

            'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'item_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        array_push($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $item_array);
    } else {


        echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="shoppingcart.php"</script>';
    }
} else {
    $item_array = array(

        'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'item_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
    );
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
}
}
```

//Function to grab array values and add it to database

```
function checkouttodatabase() {

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "precisionmice");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'precisionmice');


foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $row => $id){

    $sql="INSERT INTO orders (product, quantity, totalprice)
          VALUES ('item_id','item_quantity','item_price')";
}

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
        echo "Betaling bevestigen";
        header("refresh:2; url=checkout.php");
    } else {
        echo "Update mislukt";
    }
}
```

The function checkouttodatabase() is called when the player is redirected to a seperate webpage. Now what I would love as a result is so let's say there are two items added to the shoppingcart array. For each item added I would like it to send the variables to the MYSQL database. Except I also struggle for the total price. I would like to do it so that the quantity is multiplied by the individual item_price which is added in the MYSQL column total_price.

For example: 
Database results when submitted:

Item_id: Productname 1 ,  Item_quantity: 3, Total_price: 45.00$

Item_id: Productname 2, Item_quantity: 1, Total_price: 15.00$

Comment: You're inserting static values like `'item_id'` as a string. Instead define that as `?,?,?` and use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
to set the values.

Comment: Why do you build the same string `$sql` each and every time, but only insert the last occurence into the database? And why don't you use variables within that query?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to talk about in this code example, but to address the problem of getting an array into a database, @tadman gave you the answer in the comment above. You can't treat an array as though it were a string when composing SQL statements; you need to work with individual elements of the array instead.

If you really wanted to save an entire array into a single field of MySQL database table, you would have to serialize the array somehow, e.g., by using `json_encode()`. But you normally shouldn't be stuffing multiple values into a single database column without a compelling reason.

Comment: I've followed the page @tadman linked except now I get this error: WARNING: MYSQLI_STMT_BIND_PARAM() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE MYSQLI_STMT, BOOLEAN GIVEN IN D:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\PRECISIONMICE\STORE\SHOPCARTFUNCTIONS.PHP ON LINE 107. WARNING: MYSQLI_STMT_EXECUTE() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE MYSQLI_STMT, BOOLEAN GIVEN IN D:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\PRECISIONMICE\STORE\SHOPCARTFUNCTIONS.PHP ON LINE 108.  Which is the part 
" mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $itemname, $itemprice, $itemquantity);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); " 

Sorry if I am doing it wrong, I find MySQL and PhP rather difficult to get working.

Comment: My now code: 
`
function checkouttodatabase() {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "precisionmice");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, 'precisionmice');


   foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $row => $id){

        $itemname = "item_name";
        $itemprice = "item_price";
        $itemquantity = "item_quantity";

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO orders VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $itemname, $itemprice, $itemquantity);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}`